# SCSS Syntax definition @include font(400,16pt);

Tags: css, sass

We are using SCSS in Angular,

I am trying to understand what the 400 stands for.

Based on [Point vs Pixel: What is the difference?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/199/point-vs-pixel-what-is-the-difference), I know what 16pt means point;

- `pt` is 1/72 of an in, and
- `px` is 1/96 of an in.

Just curious what does 400 means?

```
body {
  @include font(400, 16pt);
  line-height: 24pt;
}
```

Comment: Weight I guess.

Comment: Typical font weights are 200(light), 400 (regular), 500 (medium), 700(bold), etc. `font()` is similar to a function that takes two arguments. Find the definition of `font()` in your SCSS files and you'll know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 400 is a numeric keyword values for normal [`font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight).

`font-weight` is a [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/How_CSS_works) property sets that defines how bold a font should be.

The common weight name mapping numerical keyword values from 100 to 900 roughly correspond to the [OpenType specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2#usweightclass).

Answer (score -1):

#### Related Syntax (SCSS or Sass)

See the [Sass docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) about *Mixins*:

> Mixins are included into the current context using the @include
>   at-rule, which is written `@include <name>` or `@include <name>(<arguments... >)`, with the name of the mixin being included.

So `font` is the *name* of the mixin (similar to a function), `400` and `16pt` are *arguments* to it.
To be sure you should look for the mixin named `font` in your related SCSS file. For example there could be something like:

```
@mixin font($weight, $size) {
  font-weight: $weight;
  font-size: $size;
}
```

#### Possible Meaning of `400`

Supposed `400` is related to font-properties, it most likely will be used as CSS property **[font-weight](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_font_weight.asp)**. Then this *numerical value* `400` is equivalent to `normal` font-weight, as opposed to `bold` (700) or `thin` (100).